# Add a new column that maps one character string onto a new character string based on a "Rosetta Stone" data frame?

Tags: r, gsub, dplyr

I have a data frame in R.

I'm trying to add/mutate a new column that maps several old character strings to new character strings using a map/translation/Rosetta Stone data frame that defines what strings I want to be replaced.

I was thinking something involving `dplyr::mutate` and some kind of function that applies `gsub`, but I just can't put it all together.

**Starting Data Frame:**

```
  starting_df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  ID   Genotype
  VIT_123_1    0
  ROM_456_2    0
  VIT_78_1     1
  BELG_910_1   1
")
```

**Rosetta Stone Data Frame:**

```
  map_df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  ID   New_ID
  VIT   VCO1
  ROM   VRO1
  BELG  VBE2
")
```

**Desired Output Data Frame:**

```
  >head(updated_df)
    ID           Genotype    New_ID
    VIT_123_1    0           VCO1_123_1
    ROM_456_2    0           VRO1_456_2
    VIT_78_1     1           VCO1_78_1
    BELG_910_1   1           VBE2_910_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` package.

First of all convert your `map_df` dataframe into a named vector:

```
map_v = as.character(map_df$New_ID)
names(map_v) = map_df$ID
```

Then replace the old values with new values:

```
library(stringr)
res = starting_df
res$New_ID = str_replace_all(starting_df$ID,map_v)

          ID Genotype     New_ID
1  VIT_123_1        0 VCO1_123_1
2  ROM_456_2        0 VRO1_456_2
3   VIT_78_1        1  VCO1_78_1
4 BELG_910_1        1 VBE2_910_1
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error: "`replacement` must be a character vector".  

When I try to coerce map_v to a character vector, using 
map_v <- as.character(map_v), 

I get this error:
"Error in fix_replacement(replacement) : 
  argument "replacement" is missing, with no default"

Comment: You can add `stringsAsFactors=F` when creating your map_df dataframe, so that your vectors are of type character or you can do `map_v = as.character(map_df$New_ID)` when creating map_v.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the match function, without using stringr

```
updated_df <- starting_df # this is simply because your question specifies a new dataframe
updated_df$New_ID <- map_df$New_ID[match(updated_df$ID, map_df$ID)]
```